# Using regular expressions (regex) to replace selected text in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In the example below, the text is selected using jQuery.  How can we isolate the currency by getting rid of the other data?

This attempt at using JavaScript's `replace` did not work:

```
var symbol = $("div.price > h5 > div.num").text().replace(/[\d.]*/, "");
```

This is the example HTML; the jQuery selector is working:

```
<div class="price">
  <h5 class="biguns">
    <div class="num">
      €12.28
    </div>
    Lowest Price Per Night
  </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The dot must be escaped othwerwise it will match every character and you must set the global modifier:

```
var symbol = $("div.price > h5 > div.num").text().replace(/[\d\.]+/g, "");
```

Comment: but anyway, here, knock yourself out: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html

Comment: Downvoted for the unnecessarily rude commentary. In this case,  .replace() is a Javascript method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace that shouldn't be confused with the jQuery methods http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/ and http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 3):

```
var symbol = $("div.price > h5 > div.num").text().replace(/\d+\.?\d+/, "");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't match 12 without any decimal places.  Can't always assume you'll have a consistent input.

Answer (score 0):

If the currency is always the first character and it's one character long, you could easily get it with

```
var symbol = $(".num").text().substr(0,1);
```