# JQuery replace src text

Tags: jquery, text, replace, src

How to replace the src text "web" to "mobile" for all ul>li>ing element?
Would like to change "img/web1.png" to "img/mobile1.png", "img/web2.png" to "img/mobile2.png", "img/web7.png" to "img/mobile7.png" and so on.

```
<div class="col-md-2">  
      <center><a href="#"><div class="img-circle" id="circle2">Mobile</div></a></center>
      <br/> 
</div>

<div id = "wrapper">
        <ul id = "portfolio">
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web1.png" alt = "img"/></li>
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web2.png" alt = "img"/></li>
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web3.png" alt = "img"/></li>
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web4.png" alt = "img"/></li>
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web5.png" alt = "img"/></li>
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web6.png" alt = "img"/></li> 
            <li><img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/web7.png" alt = "img"/></li> 

            <button id="zoom" type="button" class="btn btn-info"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Zoom </span> 
            </button>
        </ul> 

    </div>

    $("#circle2").click(function(){ 
      $("#portfolio>li").first().children("img").attr("src","img/mobile1.png");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through the `li` elements, find the `img` element and do a `replace` on the `src` property.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#circle2").click(function () {

        // Loop through all li elements in the 
        //     element with the id of portfolio
        $("#portfolio").find("li").each(function () {
   
            // Find the image tag
            var img = $(this).find("img");
      
            // Update the src property to the same thing, 
            //       replacing web with mobile
            img.prop("src", img.prop("src").replace("web", "mobile"));

        }); // end li loop
    }); // end change stuff click event
}); // end doc ready
```

You can see a working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ng44y7xs/)

## References:

- [JQuery String Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
- [JQuery Each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Thank you. What if the src original link is  "img/database1.png", or "img/webapp1.png", or "img/image1.png".Is there a way where I can replace all the possible different word to src="img/mobile1.png". The problem is I do not know the original word is "database or web app or image" or it could be any word

Comment: You'd probably be best with a regular expression if you're not 100% sure what text will be there, but know it will end with a number.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890680/jquery-regex-replace-from-select-text

Comment: I tried but couldn't. Do I use this?
img.prop("src", img.prop("src").replace(/[\d.]*/, "mobile"));

Answer (score 3):

This will replace all characters in the `src` file name up to the first digit with "mobile" (as per your comment above) for all `#portfolio>li>img`:

```
$("#portfolio>li>img").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/[^\/]*?(?=\d*\.png)/, "mobile"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, it only works if the code is  replace(/.*?(?=\d+)/, "img/mobile")); Is there a way that I only need to replace the word after img/ and before the digit?

Comment: Thank you. It works. Does /[^\ / ] means find any char that is not '\'?

Comment: Almost! It's "any char that is not `/`". It has to be escaped because `/` is the regex start/end character.

Comment: Is *?(?=\d*\.png) match any word that has zero or more occurrence of .png?

Comment: It matches any character followed by `XXX.png` (where X is a digit), but it doesn't capture `XXX.png`. It's called a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The `*?` at the start indicates that it's [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), i.e. it won't match more than it has to. This makes sure it doesn't consume any digits. Another way to prevent digit capture would be to add `\d` to the excluded characters, i.e. `[^\/\d]*`.