# RegEx for finding first and last names

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a string like "today is %date%, my name is %firstName% %lastName%"

Using regular expression I want to replace the %date% with todays date, same goes for firstName and lastName

I did something like

```
  let reg = new RegExp(/\%(.*?)\%/g); // this gives me the values inside % 
    val = reg.exec(value);
```

How do I replace the existing string with the values.

EDIT: If I do something like
    str.replace((/\%(.*?)\%/g), 'test');
It does replace all the values with test how do I get the value that was replaced like:

> today is %date%, my name is %firstName% %lastName%
>
> today is {{date}}, my name is {{firstName}} {{lastName}}

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with typescript

Comment: See also [Using regular expressions (regex) to replace selected text in jQuery / JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890680)

Comment: ``str.replace(/%.*?%/, m=>{m = m.slice(1,-1); console.log(`Found ${m}`); return `{{${m}}}`;});``